# References to papers/books that uses a kernel to smooth a discrete distribution

Tags: distributions, references, kernel-smoothing

Since a kernel, such as Gaussian, is often used to smooth out the distribution of discrete points in 1D, 2D or 3D, I believe there must be some study materials or research work that have used this, and I need this for references in my work.

I would appreciate if you can point me to any book/research papers/study materials that use a kernel to smooth out some distributions.

Thanks

Comment: Are you after something where the output is also discrete?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search gives you many relevant references. For instance:

`http://hub.hku.hk/bitstream/10722/60983/4/Content_15.pdf`

`http://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/my-papers/KernEstm.pdf`

`http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~vishy/introml/notes/Density.pdf`

`http://econweb.tamu.edu/li/Uncond1.pdf`

If you need more specific suggestions, you have to ask a more specific question. Otherwise, the answer is `Google Search`.

Comment: Hi. I did, but I didn't use the right keyword for the search. May I know what phrases you entered in google? I do use google search and google scholars a lot actually. Thanks.

Comment: @Simo I searched for: discrete density estimation, discrete kernel density estimation, and combinations of these using quotations. I hope this helps.